# Blank Node Red UI Dashboard after install of Dashboard

Tags: node-red

Getting blank UI after creating some dashboard nodes and deploying.

Log file from Node Red below

```
Welcome to Node-RED

17 Mar 07:56:03 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.20.2 
17 Mar 07:56:03 - [info] Node.js  version: v8.11.1 
17 Mar 07:56:03 - [info] Linux 4.14.98-v7+ arm LE 
17 Mar 07:56:06 - [info] Loading palette nodes 
17 Mar 07:56:12 - [info] Dashboard version 2.14.0 started at /ui 
17 Mar 07:56:13 - [info] Settings file  : /home/pi/.node-red/settings.js 
17 Mar 07:56:13 - [info] Context store  : 'default' [module=memory] 
17 Mar 07:56:13 - [info] User directory : /home/pi/.node-red 
17 Mar 07:56:13 - [warn] Projects disabled : editorTheme.projects.enabled=false 
17 Mar 07:56:13 - [info] Flows file : /home/pi/.node-red/stop 
17 Mar 07:56:13 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:1880/
17 Mar 07:56:13 - [warn] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
Your flow credentials file is encrypted using a system-generated key.

If the system-generated key is lost for any reason, your credentials
file will not be recoverable, you will have to delete it and re-enter
your credentials.

You should set your own key using the 'credentialSecret' option in
your settings file. Node-RED will then re-encrypt your credentials
file using your chosen key the next time you deploy a change.
---------------------------------------------------------------------

17 Mar 07:56:13 - [info] Starting flows
17 Mar 07:56:13 - [info] [mosca in:31621114.8cc84e] Binding mosca mqtt server on port: 1883
17 Mar 07:56:13 - [info] Started flows
```

If I look at the page source of 127.0.0.1:1880/UI  I see a blank page and if I look at the page source I can see this in the HTML code

Please add some UI nodes to your flow and redeploy

Even though through the browser I can't see the message

So basically the page it being displayed but when I press deploy and node red says it's deployed it doesn't update the /UI webpage

Comment: What browser are you using ?  If Chrome try to refresh your browser cache (ctrl-r)

Comment: Also you should probable include your flow in the question.